# How to view voltage graph in simulink

Tags: power, simulation, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics

I am trying to simulate Synchronous Buck DC DC converter I have created the circuit now i want to test it to check whether it is giving me the correct output or not , I have tried the same circuit in LTSPice but there it is very easy to check the output but in simulink ihave tried every sink scope/block to attach to the output but it wont attach for e.g in this diagram i am trying to attach a voltage measurement block but i wouldnt , what can i do to view the output ?[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things missing in your model

1) reference. Place a GND node on the - of the main source

2) connect the voltage monitoring block. Right now the voltage monitoring block isn't connected (red traces)

3) suitable sink connected to the voltage measurement. A scope is fine (remember to turn off last 5000samples only). I prefer workspace sinks and to plot in figures.

Finally make sure you simulation runs long enough for an output to appear (no point running for 1ms if things don't start occurring for 10ms)

--edit--

Those appear to be simscape parts not simpower systems. That voltage monitor is from simpowersystems.